# TextInput fullscreen onFocus react native

Tags: react-native, styles, textinput

Hi is there a way to make an multiline TextInput go fullscreen onFocus and return to its normal size after the user finished editting (for ex: when the user hits the android Back button).

I plan to allow user to type a long paragraph in my App, and I think it would improve the UX if I can make the multiline text go fullscreen when user typing.

I imagine a multiline TextInput like that would be a helpful for many other developers as well, it's shocking that I couldn't find a pre-built component like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is to put a TouchableOpacity with an `onPress` listener around the TextInput and have it navigate to another screen which has a full-screen text input and receives the onChange listener via params (there will be a [warning](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state) with react-navigation-5 but in most cases you can safely ignore it).